# How to change the order of open "tabbed forms" in MS Access via VBA

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, tabs

I am using "tabbed document" forms in MS Access (each main form that is open has a "tab" to allow users to easily move between forms).

Does anyone know of a way to reorder such opened forms via VBA? I have workaround code that closes all the forms and then re-opens them in the order I need, but it is clunky and slow (some of the forms are big so take a while to load, and often users have applied filters/sorts which I then need to individually re-apply, plus resetting the current record etc etc).

As all I need is to change the order of the forms on-screen, so my approach seems like overkill - but I can't seem to find info on how to do this anywhere!

(FYI I am NOT talking about the order of pages within a tab control, to avoid any confusion!)

Please attached screenshot with three tabbed forms open, I'd like to re-arrange them so eg left to right they become: @Home, Booking Detail, Enquiry Detail

[image: 3 tabbed forms]

Thanks

Comment: Access does not support changing the order.  It cannot be done... without impossible workarounds.  I tried this at one time, researching and experimenting and never got it to work.  More power to anyone who can post a reliable, reasonable solution, but I bet that will not happen.  I normally don't post "negative" answers, but you will likely waste your time waiting for an answer and even more time trying to make something work from various suggestions on the web.

Comment: If you close and reopen in the desired order and that works, why are they open to begin with? Why need to change order? I never used tabbed documents, only overlapping windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I have inadvertently figured this out.

In testing I found that if you hide a tabbed form, when you unhide it, it doesn't show up in the same position, but in fact now shows as the last form (ie the rightmost tab)

Eureka! Now to reorder the forms I simply hide them, and then unhide them in the order required. Combine this with DoCmd.Echo = False and there is, in my testing, virtually zero overhead.

Phew!

Comment: Just for anyone stumbling on this anwser. While this works rather well, there is a caveat: the order in `Application.Forms` will *not* be updated (e.g. the last opened form will still be the last). You won't be able to tell the real "order" after this reordering using hide/show.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is not seeing all the forms at once, you don't need to waste resource/time loading all forms at once. Load only what the user supposed to see. NavigationControl is very good for that.

**Method 1**

Move from tabbed documents to `NavigationControl`. Each tab is loaded `OnDemand` hence your main form start-up would be much more quicker. If the main and tabbed form are related to each other,  use tabbed form's `OnOpen` event to dynamically change the record source.

I.e. `Form_Open => me.RecordSource = Select * form T1 where T1.id = ParentForm.Id`

**Method 2**

If you can't move to Navigation control, simulate the same effect as above.
When tab pages are changed/selected => underlying form gets a record source.

I.e.

```
Private Sub TabCtl2_Change()
    If Me.TabCtl2.value = 1 Then
        me.subform1.recordsource    = source
        me.subform1.LinkChildFields = linkingFieldName 'if related
        me.subform1.LinkChildFields = LinkMasterFields 'if related
    ElseIf Me.TabCtl2.value = 2 Then
        'Your other form
    end if
End Sub
```

This can help you to reduce your loading time.

**[Cascading result sets]**
In case if all of your forms are showing cascading results, you might want to consider remove record-source for all of your subforms and then re-apply at each selection.

The goal is to minimise loading time and show only necessary data the user is supposed to see/want to see. Hope this helps to have some idea.

Comment: Hi Krish, thanks for this. In fact this is basically what I already do. Users open forms as needed, and sub-forms are loaded dynamically as you suggest. This is not the issue. 

The issue is I used to load all forms, and they loaded in a set order. Now users load the forms themselves, the order can be different - and they don't like it! So I'd like an easy way to re-order the open forms, WITHOUT closing and re-opening (which is what I currently do)

Comment: Not sure what you are on about. Please add screenshots if you can. @Jaspos

Comment: I have re-edited the question to add a screenshot, and what I am trying to achieve